# How do I use my own domain for my own openID login without having to make a myopenid domain account?

Tags: openid

I have my own domain signed-up under myOpenID as follows:

```
openid.mysite.com
```

Everything is verified and seems to be working properly on the myOpenID site. However, now I want to setup my website so I only have to enter the domain name as my openID login.

I have read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/ and understand the basic concept using header link tags. However, instead of...

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://username.myopenid.com/">
```

I want to use my own site for the openid.delegate as follows...

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://openid.example.com/username" />
```

And this works on my site with no problems! However, I only plan to have one user authenticated through my site, me. I do not plan on having any other users, so I would simply like to have...

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://openid.example.com" />
```

...note the lack of username in the openid.delegate href. I want to do this not only for a shorter link href, but also so I don't have to make a domain account on myopenid.com, adding yet another login, etc.

Does that make sense? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [phpMyID (http://siege.org/phpmyid.php)](http://siege.org/phpmyid.php), I know it is deprecated and no longer maintained - but it works and I use it on my own domain. All you need is that your hosted domain supports php scripts, and since most of them do - it should not be a problem.